Gaussian fluctuations reducing $T_c$ in Goldenfeld chapter 6
I am trying to understand generally how the critical temperature is shifted relative to its mean-field predictions even in dimensions greater than the critical dimension. This question is related to whether the stringent Gaussian approximation can describe the lowering of the critical temperature at all (with a focus on a simple $\phi^4$ theory and on the Hubbard-Stratonovich Ising field theory).
It is often stated that fluctuations reduce the critical temperature away from its mean-field value. Chapter 6 of Goldenfeld considers simple Gaussian fluctuations coming from quadratic terms in the action about the saddle point, but there seems naively to be conflicting statements about whether these fluctuations suppress the critical temperature.
Problem 6-3 considers evaluating the partition function of the Hubbard-Stratonovich Ising field theory for a constant field $H$ and a nearest-neighbor coupling matrix $J$
$$Z \propto \int \prod_{i=1}^N d \phi_i e^{\frac{\beta}{2} (\phi_i-H) J_{ij}^{-1} (\phi_j-H)  - \sum_i \log(\cosh(\beta \phi_i))} $$
in the Gaussian approximation, which is, as far as I see, just a saddle point calculation that includes the integration over a quadratic action (neglecting the higher order terms). By including an external field $H$, the susceptibility is calculated to diverge at a temperature below the mean-field temperature.
However, in the body of the chapter, Goldenfeld considers the field theory
$$Z = \int D \phi e^{-\beta \int_V d^d r \left[\frac{1}{2} \gamma (\nabla \phi)^2 - H \eta +a t \eta^2 + \frac{1}{2} b \eta^4 \right]}.$$
The mean-field critical point occurs when $t=0$, and Goldenfeld finds via an integral of the two-point function (i.e. the usual static susceptibility sum rule) that $\chi_T \propto \frac{1}{t}$. That is, despite including Gaussian fluctuations, the susceptibility still diverges at the naive mean-field critical point.
I recognize that these two field theories have some key differences, but it's unclear to me why the critical temperature is suppressed in the former but not the latter. What is going on?

Some of the differences:

Discrete lattice in the former, spatial continuum in the latter

Different definitions of the susceptibilities (derivatives with respect to $H$ versus integral of two-point function)

More complicated $H$ and $\beta$ dependence of the coefficients in the former


However, I don't yet see why any of these could make a difference.
